# microsoft access requery updates form after 2 requeries

Tags: sql, forms, ms-access, vba

So I have a form (A) , a form (B) , and a table (X). Both forms are based from queries of table (X). The user may click on form A and it will open form B filtered to what that user clicked on. The vba for this works, and is:

```
docmd.openform "formB" , , , "mykey = " & me.mykey
```

Once the user is on form B, they have the ability to update table (X) using a combobox dropdown. The user on form B may select a record and a dropdown next to the record that changes information on table X. Once the information is changed, it is updated in the backend table accordingly.

My problem is that these changes are not reflected in either form. The vba I tried to use to update the forms is
    forms!formB.requery
    forms!formA.requery

The strange thing is that if I click on form A and reopen form B to change a 2nd record, I can now see the previous update. So the 2nd requery updates properly for the first change. Any ideas?

Comment: My guess is that your `forms!formB.requery` are incorrect. Try simply `Me.Requery` and see what happens (if it does anything). Or `Me.formB.Requery`

Comment: tried both of those, did not do anything. When i run [forms!formB.requery] i can see the requery taking place in the bottom right of access. So i believe the VBA is correct, just something to do with how i set up the forms or table or something is wrong.

Comment: Try this, as a simple test again : `Me.Refresh`.. What handler are you using to trigger the `Requery`?

Comment: @barker: You may want to try DBEngine.Idle dbRefreshCache before you call your Requery commands - maybe the data has not been flushed yet?  If all else fails, maybe DoCmd.Requery instead of form.Requery.  Documentation says it takes a bit longer, but it closes and reopens the underlying query.  Not sure if it will have a substantial difference, though.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug in access, not my code. If a combo box has focus when the requery is ran it will not update forms properly, although the table in the back end will still update. I fixed it by added code to the combo box that changes focus after update, now it works.

Comment: Glad you got this working.  Did you find any documentation found on the behaviour, please?  Looking to do some research on this.  Thanks.

Comment: It's right in the MS Documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff191903%28v=office.15%29.aspx  If you omit the object specified by expression, the Requery method requeries the underlying data source for the form or control that has the focus. If the control that has the focus has a record source or row source, it will be requeried; otherwise, the control's data will simply be refreshed.